# PUT method using Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I try to update my user by putting some new fields inside for example `firstName` and `lastName`. In server console I get 200 status but is nothing added to the object. Any idea what am I doing wrong in this?

This is from my userAction.js

```
export function updateUserData(firstName, lastName) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    const state = getState();
    const { user_id, token } = state.auth;
    return axios.put(USER_DATA(user_id), { firstName, lastName }, {
      headers: { authorization: token }
    }).then((response) => {
      dispatch(updatedUserData(response.data));
      console.log(response.data)
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch(console.log("Couldn't update user data."));
    });
  };
}
```

this is from my authenticationController.js file from backend

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, {
    $set: {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      userData: [{
        role: req.body.role,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        cscs: req.body.cscs,
        address: [{
          number: req.body.number,
          street: req.body.street,
          city: req.body.city,
          postcode: req.body.postcode
        }],
      }],
    }
  }, { upsert: true }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(user);
    }
  })
}
```

my router.js

```
router.route('/users/:user_id/data')
  .get(requireAuth, AuthenticationController.index)
  .put(requireAuth, AuthenticationController.update);
```

and here is a response after update

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0df225287cc77612ed89a5"),
    "email" : "user@user.com",
    "password" : "$2HbyP4.ts9O/zrjV5Pcd/Z28bhOb8oGas9wEG",
    "userData" : [ 
        {
            "firstName" : "First Name",
            "lastName" : "Last Name",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b0df225287cc77612ed89a6"),
            "address" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0df225287cc77612ed89a7")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Is the 200 status for your response? and also pls post what you get in your console.log and the data you sent ie, the contents of USER_DATA(user_id), { firstName, lastName }

Comment: @RohithMurali as you can see in the code above there is a console.log if I use response.data I receive the object response from db if I use response.status is 200

Comment: Did you try a request with postman or some rest tools to see whether the api is actually working?

Comment: In Postman is updating it

Comment: Ok, then can you pls post more details like the values in your content body and the url. You can also compare the requests between your api call from browser and postman in a fiddler and see the difference to find what you are missing.

Comment: @RohithMurali please check my updated post.